# Fast compute of F*P*FT matrix product

Tags: matrices, matrix-multiplication

Let $P$ be a symmetric (positive definite, if that helps...) matrix of size $n$.

Let $F$ be a matrix of size $n$.

- Is there an existing efficient algorithm implementation to calculate $FPF^T$ ?
- Is there an even more efficient existing implementation for the special case where $F$ is upper triangular ?

To give some context, I'm particularly interested in $20\leq n\leq50$ - typically not that large of a dimensionality.

In both cases, I could "dumbly" loop over the upper elements of the resulting matric and calculate the results, eg for the second case ($F$ upper triangular)

$$R(i,j \geq i)=\sum_{k\geq i}F(i,k)\sum_{l\geq j}P(k,l)F(j,l)$$

but it's not obvious to me if that would end up being significantly faster than plain fully vectorialized / optimized double matrix multiplication.

Comment: The exponents are too small to benefit from fast multiplication algorithms such as Strassen's.

Comment: When $P$ is symmetric, you can save half of the computations as about all terms are duplicate. But nothing better. With an upper triangular $F$, you can gain a further factor $3$, I guess.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : sure, and I can myself code a "dumb" function that would loop over each element of the result and provide the result according to elements of P and F. But I'm not sure it would be faster than an efficient, vectorialized general double multiplication.

Comment: What more do you want ?

Comment: Something that makes use of some linear algebra properties that would allow for a smarter way of computing things ? Maybe I should have asked in math instead of cs

Comment: There is no smarter way.